# How can I make the Headphone with Speaker works together to play the sound?

Tags: java, android

I need to make the speaker with the headphone play the sound together in the code, I don't even know if it's feasible or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is absolutely feasible. Because if it wouldn't have been then when someone calls you on your android phone, if you have noticed, the ringtone can be heard on both the headphone as well as the speaker.

What you need to do is set the mediaplayer's AudioStreamType to AudioManager.STREAM_RING

```
    player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
    player.start();
```

Comment: This may have an undesired effect on Bluetooth headphones so that the music plays on voice-quality, which is trash for music . I don't really know though, just putting my two cents.